# Color Histogram

Tags: colors

I'm trying to calculate histogram for an image. I'm using the following formula to calculate the bin

```
%bin = red*(N^2) + green*(N^1) + blue;
```

I have to implement the following Matlab functions.

```
[row, col, noChannels] = size(rgbImage);
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(rgbImage); % Ranges from 0 to 1.
H = zeros(4,4,4);
for col = 1 : columns
    for row = 1 : rows
       hBin = floor(hsvImage(row, column, 1) * 15);
       sBin = floor(hsvImage(row, column, 2) * 4);
       vBin = floor(hsvImage(row, column, 3) * 4);
       F(hBin, sBin, vBin) = hBin, sBin, vBin + 1;
    end
end
```

When I run the code I get the following error message "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logical."

As I am new to Matlab and Image processing, I'm not sure if the problem is with implementing the algorithm or a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code. (Four if you count that you changed from `H` to `F` your accumulator vector, but I'll assume that's a typo.)

First one, your variable `bin` can be zero at any moment if the values of a giving pixel are low. And `F(0)` is not a valid index for a vector or matrix. This is why you are getting that error.

You can solve easily by doing `F(bin+1)` and keep in mind that your `F` vector will have your values shifted one position over.

Second error, you are assigning the value `bin + 1` to your accumulator vector `F`, which is not what you want, you want to add 1 every time a pixel in that range is found, what you should do is `F(bin+1) = F(bin+1) + 1;`. This way the values of `F` will be increasing all the time.

Third error is simpler, you forgot to implement your `bin = red*(N^2) + green*(N^1) + blue;` equation